# What species mimics two others?

Tags: predation

Richard Dawkins in 'the selfish gene':

> But there are species of mimic that do something very strange. Some individuals of the species mimic one nasty species; other individuals mimic another. ... One butterfly may mimic species A while his brother mimics species B.

What is an example of such a species, along with the two species its members mimic?

Answer (score -1):

How about Mimic Octopus? they mimic sea snake, lionfish, and others. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimic_octopus

Comment: Thanks Polypipe wrangler.  Dawkins seems to have something else in mind:  One allele in the gene pool that makes the butterfly look one way, another allele (for the same gene or gene complex) that makes the butterfly look another way.  Not a shape-shifter!  I'd like to know a specific butterfly species like that.